# Xorg not starting after converting Manjaro to Arch

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xorg, nvidia, manjaro

I recently decided to convert Manjaro to Arch, since I didn't have a USB to install it from. I successfully converted it, installed the 5.10.26-1-lts kernel. After setting up xorg I tried to start it and got this error

```
[    34.030] (WW) Failed to open protocol names file lib/xorg/protocol.txt
[    34.031] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.10
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    34.032] Build Operating System: Linux Arch Linux
[    34.032] Current Operating System: Linux linux-setup 5.10.26-1-lts #1 SMP Thu, 25 Mar 2021 08:56:04 +0000 x86_64
[    34.033] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-linux-lts root=UUID=fc5f80f1-ac69-48d3-80f2-48c8b5487b65 rw quiet apparmor=1 security=apparmor resume=UUID=2a0edcde-6c33-43dc-a98a-5c30a4bef739 udev.log_priority=3
[    34.034] Build Date: 14 December 2020  12:10:29PM
[    34.034]  
[    34.034] Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
[    34.035]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    34.035] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    34.037] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Mar 27 16:17:25 2021
[    34.041] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    34.041] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    34.044] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[    34.044] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[    34.044] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[    34.044] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[    34.044] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[    34.044] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[    34.044] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    34.044] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    34.044] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    34.044] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[    34.044] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    34.048] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1" does not exist.
[    34.048]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    34.052] (==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/misc,
        /usr/share/fonts/TTF,
        /usr/share/fonts/OTF,
        /usr/share/fonts/100dpi,
        /usr/share/fonts/75dpi
[    34.052] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    34.052] (**) Extension "COMPOSITE" is enabled
[    34.052] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[    34.052] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[    34.052] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[    34.052] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    34.052]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    34.052]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.1
[    34.052]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[    34.052]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[    34.053] (++) using VT number 3

[    34.054] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_31
[    34.056] (--) PCI:*(1@0:0:0) 10de:1380:1458:36d1 rev 162, Mem @ 0xf6000000/16777216, 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    34.056] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[    34.056] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    34.060] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    34.071] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.071]    compiled for 1.20.10, module version = 1.0.0
[    34.071]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[    34.071] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    34.071] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[    34.078] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    34.078]    compiled for 1.6.99.901, module version = 1.0.0
[    34.078]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    34.078] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  460.67  Thu Mar 11 00:09:07 UTC 2021
[    34.078] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    34.079] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    34.079] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    34.079] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    34.081] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.081]    compiled for 1.20.10, module version = 1.0.0
[    34.081]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    34.081] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[    34.081] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[    34.082] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    34.084] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.084]    compiled for 1.20.10, module version = 1.0.0
[    34.084]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    34.084] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    34.084] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    34.084] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    34.087] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Please see the
[    34.087] (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages and
[    34.087] (EE) NVIDIA:     consult the NVIDIA README for details.
[    34.087] (EE) No devices detected.
[    34.087] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    34.087] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[    34.087] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    34.087] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    34.087] (EE) 
[    34.103] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

I am running a GTX 750ti graphics card. I am not sure how to fix this.
This is the guide that I followed ~ https://kabirnayeem99.medium.com/manjaro-to-arch-conversation-5fe4c70999f6

Comment: `lsmod | egrep 'nvid|nouv'` ?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Nothing showed up. I'm on fish and it gave me an error, but no output.

Comment: Your NVIDIA kernel modules are either not built or not loaded. As to why - I've no idea. You should be seeing `nvidia_uvm nvidia_drm nvidia_modeset nvidia i2c_nvidia_gpu`

Comment: Some basic steps to investigate your issue: 1) Did you install the proprietary NVIDIA driver alongside Manjaro? Or the open source nouveau? `pacman -Qs nvidia` and `pacman -Qs nouveau` will tell you if they are currently installed. You may then check if any of the modules is blacklisted in `/etc/modprobe.d/`.

Comment: I just decided to install Arch from an installation media.